# Class "Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar" not found in setup/src/Magento/Setup/registration.php:9

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, plugin, magento2.4.5

When I run "composer install or "composer update" command from my magento 2.4.5 root folder I am getting this error.

```
- Installing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (2.4.0): Extracting archive
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar" not found in /public_html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/registration.php:9
Stack trace:
#0 /public_html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(29): require_once()
#1 [internal function]: Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}()
#2 /public_html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(31): array_map()
#3 /home/admin/domains/fitnessyantra.com/public_html/app/etc/NonComposerComponentRegistration.php(34): Magento\NonComposerComponentRegistration\{closure}()
```

When I run the same commands with no plugin i.e "composer install --no-plugins" then I am not getting the error.
Can you help me on this how can I solve this "composer install" without no-plugin issue

Answer (score 4):

The [official system requirements for Magento 2.4.5](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/installation-guide/system-requirements.html) state that Composer 2.2 is supported.

However, as of the time of writing, Composer 2.2.0 throws the error you posted during `composer install` or `composer update` commands.

This bug has been fixed in later versions of Composer 2.2.  Running the following command first should resolve the issue.

```bash
sudo composer global self-update -- 2.2.18
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the composer.json file specifically the **require-dev** section with what is written here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4.5/composer.json

Then remove **vendor** folder and run `composer install`.

Comment: ok, let me try it.

Comment: I did remove vendor folder and tried but still the same issue. When I run the composer:install --no-plugins then I don't see this error but I need to install with plugins.

Comment: Please try to clear composer cache by running command: `composer clearcache`, then remove **vendor** folder and run `composer install`.

Comment: Yes I cleared composer cache and ran the composer install command but still the same issue. I am facing this issue at "laminas-dependency-plugin" module. This is the error : Installing laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin (2.5.0): Extracting archive
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar" not found in ../app/code/Smartwave/Megamenu/registration.php:6

Comment: this issue not only occur with Smartwave/Megamenu module. For example if I remove that module and run the composer install then the same issue is showing at the next running module. If I remove all the third party modules then the same issue showing at core module registration.php file

Comment: I don't see you mentioned removing the vendor folder in the above comment, can you confirm? If the issue still persist, try to remove `composer.lock` file and `vendor` folder. Then run `composer install`, then `bin/magento setup:upgrade`,  then `bin/magento setup:di:compile` and
`bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: I am renaming "vendor" folder to "vendor-old" something like that and running composer install. let me try removing composer.lock file as well this time and let you know the result.

Comment: I did remove "vendor" and "composer.lock" file from the magento root and ran composer install command but after few secs I am getting the same error.

Comment: I've updated the answer, please give it a try.

Comment: sure I will try it

Comment: No luck, I am getting this error at "laminas-dependency-plugin". when I run the composer install with --no-plugins then I am not getting this error. Is there anything do I need to change to work with plugins ?

Comment: What composer version you are using? Can you confirm you are upgrading from an older version to 2.4.5? If yes, what is that version?

Comment: I did not upgraded. I installed fresh magento 2.4.5 vennila and I am using composer 2.2.

Comment: So, I would like to suggest you remove the current magento folder, database and re-install magento 2.4.5, is it fine?

Comment: ok. will try that. thank you :)

Comment: @shankarboss Do you have any updates on this?

Comment: Please try with check the class directory. it should be under lib/magento